# How can I add the registry key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am using a .net application. I want to add the following registry key to the application.

```
HKLM\Software\Business Objects\Suite 11.5\Components\DHTMLViewer\EncodeHTMLForSingleLineFieldObjects
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Microsoft.Win32.Registry class

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKLM\Software\Business Objects\Suite 11.5\Components\DHTMLViewer", "EncodeHTMLForSingleLineFieldObjects", "my value");

var value = Registry.GetValue(@"HKLM\Software\Business Objects\Suite 11.5\Components\DHTMLViewer", "EncodeHTMLForSingleLineFieldObjects", null);
```